# Display brightness goes two shades darker if I am idle for 10-11 seconds

Tags: power-management, brightness

The display brightness comes down 2 shades darker if I'm idle for 10-11secs!! It automatically dims itself :o and it's very distracting!

Earlier this could be avoided through power management, by the "dim display brightness while idle" setting and setting the time limit. Now, apparently, it's not available there?

Is there a way out?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To adjust the screen brightness, click on the dash and search for *Screen*. Open *Screen* settings and you can then adjust your screen brightness settings from there.

[image]